# Feedback on "book summary" originated from master's thesis

Tags: thesis, books, feedback

I am transforming my Mater thesis into a book. I need to write a 100 word summary for the same as well. Should I be mentioning in my book that it is an extension of my Master's thesis? The following is the relevant excerpt from my book summary.

"**This book, which originates from author’s master’s thesis, discusses laser-based ultrasonic NDT method.**"

Comment: This is not a forum; it is a place for people to ask questions,not give the members assignments!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a question - it's an attempt to give an assignment to members

Comment: Please see the changes I  have made if they make it more on-topic now.

Comment: What do you need the summary for? If it's the publisher asking for a summary there's a good chance the summary 1) becomes the blurb at the back of the book and 2) ends up on all the marketing flyers they make.

Comment: Yes, it kind of a promotional statement that the publisher has asked requested me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would not refer to your master thesis in your abstract. Often books are recommended based on an author’s life long in depth experience in a field. In your case I would look for recommendations of professors and put those on the cover of your book.